# CSS background-position doesn't help to change where the image is

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

by default styles are that:

```
.landing-icon.self-service-badge:before {
   background-image: url("/images/Evolution/site/self-service-badge.svg");
   height: 76px;
   width: 76px;
}
```

and image is centered. but when using internet explorer, background image is on the left side. i tried this:

```
.landing-icon.self-service-badge:before {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url("/images/Evolution/site/self-service-badge.svg");
    height: 76px;
    width: 76px;
}
```

but this doesn't work for me, image is still on the left side, what can you advice?

Comment: which version of internet explorer are you using?

Comment: Could you put up a snippet which we can run as at the moment the CSS isn't enough to test things - I imagine there must be other settings (such as having the :before with a content: ''; property) which make it work on other browsers.

Comment: Please also provide the related html code. We need a code snippet which can run and can [reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So that we can have a test and see how to help.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried using auto-align, here is an exemple.

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}
```